# Quick add card in Trello from anywhere (similar to Todoist)

Tags: trello

Is it possible to create a new card in Trello like it is possible with Todoist App on Mac? With Todoist I have a custom command (in my case cmd+alt+.) to add a todo from anywhere. It then just opens a small popup in the Toolbar.

See here:
[image: Quick add todo with Todoist App for Mac]

**Is there any third party app that does exactly that?**

I ask because I currently have to go to the browser, open Trello, go into a board and add the card - which is very time consuming.

I also made a "native" app via Fluid, but the workflow of adding is still the same (more infos on the official "Trello Resources" Board: https://trello.com/c/U5pLbLyp/88-trello-fluid-app-mac-desktop-app)

Also went through the whole Lists "Browser Extensions" and "Integrations/Utilities" at the above mentioned Trello Resources link. Still no solution.
http://pilotmoon.com/popclip/extensions/page/Trello is only a part of the solution, as I need to mark some text and then be able to send to a Trello board.
The downside is, that you have to install PopClip and then install the Trello extension and PopClip changes your whole appearance of the right-click on a Mac.

Comment: Be careful asking for recommendations for apps; focus on the problem you're trying to solve. See also [How do I ask a question that may require recommending a web app?](http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/q/3705/354)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Added some more infos of how my solution path was. Imo I am providing the problem description and the approach how I tried to solve it.

Comment: If you need to mark text on a website and send to a Trello board, you can easily use the Trello bookmarklet to do so. Doesn't work from the file system though. See: https://trello.com/add-card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As promised here is the tool, called **Naisone's Trello Quick Add**: https://github.com/bensinther/naisone-trello-quick-add

You can make the Quick Add view appear globally via **cmd+alt+k** on a Mac and **ctrl+alt+a** on both Mac and Windows.

The tool is very simple (BS Bingo Time: KISS - keep it simple and stupid) and helps me a lot on a daily basis.
You can enter a Card Title, Card Description and select the Board and List where to add that card to.
It also remembers your last selection of board and list, which makes it much easier for fast adding cards.

[image: Naisone Trello Quick Add Screenshot]

I will make the app also available for download (current problem is the file size of over 100 MB - as it is based on Electron. I don't know if users accept such a big file size for such a small app inside the Mac App Store). Currently the user needs to compile the app manually and be familiar with Node/Bower/Gulp.

Answer (score 3):

I also find it takes a lot of time to get to a Board or Card in Trello's web interface, so I wrote a [command line Trello app called Trelew](https://github.com/websitesfortrello/trelew).

If you like the terminal, it will probably solve your problem.

I find it much easier to type a few commands on the terminal, get to the current board, add cards, comment or update the description, then leave, then it is to open the web interface.

Comment: Nice. I am also currently writing an application (based on Electron) which solves the problem of just hitting a shortcut on the keyboard and a small window appears. For non Terminal users the best approach. Will update here when I make it available on Github.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a small utility for Mac to quickly add cards to Trello.

Quick Entry for Trello -  is a FREE and simple utility for Mac which allows you to add cards quickly to Trello Board from anywhere ->
[homepage](http://www.noteifyapp.com/quick-entry-for-trello/)